# Synonyme de « langue maternelle » en un seul mot

Tags: synonymes, mots-composés

Je me demandais s'il existe un synonyme de l'expression *langue maternelle* mais en un seul et unique mot.

Comment: À part [L1](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/L1), je ne vois pas.

Comment: @suiiurisesse c'est un _adjectif_ possessif mais sinon, je plussoie

Answer (score 4):

Il n'y en a pas, en dehors de l'abréviation [L1](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/L1) déjà évoquée par Toto, mais on pourrait inventer la chimérique *[matri](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/matri-)[glosse](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-glosse)<sup>1</sup>*...

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Pour l'instant, un seul *hit* sur Google ;-)</sub>

Comment: ...et le SEO de chez Estée Lauder ?? ;)

Comment: @suiiurisesse No sé, peut être un "Matte Gloss" prononcé à la chinoise ?

Answer (score 1):

Il semble effectivement ne pas y avoir de synonyme direct. Tout est donc affaire de contexte. Si les autres éléments le permettent, on peut légitimement employer *idiome*, *dialecte* ou *patois*. Ces termes caractérisent en effet des langues peu ou pas écrites et qui, par définition, s'apprennent oralement. Dans une écrasante majorité des cas il s'agit de la famille et des proches, c'est bien la langue "maternelle", celle de l'enfance.

Exemple : « Je lui posais ma question en anglais mais il me répondit dans son idiome » a de bonnes chances d'être compris comme « dans sa langue maternelle ».
Bien entendu, si la langue visée est une grande langue internationale identifiable, cela ne s'applique pas. On peut alors employer le nom de la langue.

N. B. J'ai vécu et travaillé comme Français en Suisse alémanique (Zürich) : la *Muttersprache* y est bien le suisse allemand (dialectal) et non ce qu'on appelle le « bon allemand » qui ne s'apprend qu'à partir de 6-7 ans dans le système scolaire.

Answer (score 1):

> Ma, ta, sa langue.

Je triche puisque c'est un mot (*langue*) avec un [déterminant possessif](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3485) mais sans autre précision ça convient bien et la langue dans laquelle on s'exprime couramment à un moment particulier dans le temps n'est pas communément « ma, ta, sa langue ».